# GLSL works weirdly for creating depth G-Buffer

Tags: glsl, shader, depth

Following pictures is geometry rendering result.

Jesus! I have no enough reputation. Then i can't attach my picture.
I describe the geometry, instead attach my picture.

**geometry is flat rectangle.**

Then following code is glsl source for creating depth g-buffer.

--- Vertex Shader ---

```
varying float uv_depth;

void main (void) 
{
    vec4 pos = modelview_mat * vec4(v_pos,1.0);
    gl_Position = projection_mat * pos;
    uv_depth = gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w;
}
```

--- Fragment Shader ---

```
varying float uv_depth;

void main (void)
{
    float depthNormalized = uv_depth * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 color = packFloatToVec4i(depthNormalized);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The function, packFloatToVec4i is a just packing function. It's not so important.

Like i said above, the geometry is flat rectangle.
So I expected very smooth image. But it don't.
Depth g-buffer is weird.

As I expected, some parts is smooth. But whole is not.
Some parts have harsh undulation.

I thought easy to making depth G-buffer.
But i lost my way to go.
Is there some problem on my code?
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your `varying float uv_depth` logic is not necessary.

If you understand the transformations (projection, perspective divide, viewport mapping) OpenGL uses to get to window-space (`gl_FragCoord`), you will find that you do not need to write `uv_depth` at all.

What the line `float depthNormalized = uv_depth * 0.5 + 0.5;` in your fragment shader computes is actually the same value that `gl_FragCoord.z` stores. You have basically re-invented the viewport transformation (depth range), which already happens automatically.

#### You may get better results if you write your fragment shader this way:

```
void main (void)
{
    vec4 color = packFloatToVec4i(gl_FragCoord.z);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Ideally you do not even need to use a color texture to store depth. `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` image formats are much more efficient and do not require special packing and unpacking, they can store a single-component with the necessary precision to store your depth.

Comment: Thank you~ :) I knew that is not problem. Real problem is another part of program. and I understand your answer. That good~ Thank you for you kindly answer.